# How to check if a variable is of type "void" in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, variables, types, void

Here is the case. I forgot to return nil at the end of a method and caused a bad access error in the following code.

```
- (NSString*) testWithRet{
    NSString* ret = @"js";
    //return ret;
}
```

...

```
NSString* var = [obj testWithRet];
//can I check here to prevent the bad access below?
NSLog(@"%@", var); // bad access here
```

My question is, can I do any checking before the bad access occurs?

I have tried to check "var" against nil and NULL but failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Frankly I don't know. On the other hand - isn't it better to let it happen? This is something I'd rather fix the root cause than checking for it afterwards. And didn't the compiler sort of complain about not returning a value?

Comment: Yes. Xcode gives me a warning "Control reaches end of non-void function". However, the case is, I am writing a library that will be used by other people. It would be better if I can provide any message to the users for debugging. Thanks.

Comment: The calling function/method will be fetch some unpredicatble address off the stack. Most likely this will not be 0. Therefore checking for nil will not work. All other checks that I could think of will have to access the object. And accessing it could cause a memory violation or some inpredictable result. @Dukeland, especially as you are developing a library that is supposed to be used in other programs, you should be keen to get rid of all warnings!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do any checking like that: letting a value-returning function end without `return` is *undefined behavior*, the value "returned" in such cases is, well, undefined.

You need to watch out for warnings in Xcode, and fix them all. In this particular case you should get a message that says

> Control reaches end of non-void function

on the line of the closing curly brace of your non-void function. This should be your signal to add a missing `return` to your code.

Comment: Please, make (at least some) of your Warnings as Errors. This will prevent this from happening at all.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

```
NSString* var = [obj testWithRet];
//can I check here to prevent the bad access below?
if([var isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", var); // bad access here
}
```

Comment: No. "bad access" at this line.
if([var isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

Comment: That is bound to fail. Even if - in the most unliekly event - var contains an NSString object, then it will certainly not be the one, taht the caller wanted to fetch.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I didn't understand what u meant. Replicate the same situation on a mac application u can see that the above solution holds good.